# How to make the selection of individual series dynamic in highcharts even after setting max and min?

Tags: highcharts, scaling

When we set the yaxis max and min the scale becomes fixed. If we just want to see the individual series by hiding other series, How can it be dynamic instead of fixed scale ?

```
yAxis: {min: 0, max: 100}
```

For example in the following fiddle, when I hide series 2, is it possible to adjust the scale of for the remaining series dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/H2pyC/38/

Thanks

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/H2pyC/39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roll your own [`events.legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        shadow: true,
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function (event) {
                var theChart = this.chart;
                console.log(theChart);
                theChart.yAxis[0].update({
                    max: null,
                    min: null
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you have to do is set the `yAxis` min and max to `null`. This lets highcharts determine the dynamic min/max values. You would probably want it to keep track of the on-load min/max so that when you re-enable all series it sets the min/max to how it was on-load.